# Either the step is already declared or Mink instance has not been set on Mink context class

Tags: php, behat

I'm trying to use make some tests around a Drupal project (but Behat is out of it), however I'm having trouble around Mink and its session, and I must admit I have no clue about what I am doing.

Here are my files so far:

**FeatureContext.php**

```
use Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\RawDrupalContext; #not used
use Behat\Mink\Exception\ExpectationException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException;
use Behat\Mink\Session;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context; #not used
use Behat\Mink\Mink;
use DMore\ChromeDriver\ChromeDriver;


/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements SnippetAcceptingContext {

  protected $mink;

  /**
   * FeatureContext constructor.
   * Initializes context.
   * PLEASE NOTE THAT I'M NOT SURE ABOUT THIS, BUT IT SEEMS TO WORK SO FAR
   * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
   * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
   * context constructor through behat.yml.
   */
  public function __construct() {
    $this->mink = new Mink(array(
      'browser' => new Session(new ChromeDriver('http://localhost:9222', null, 'http://www.website.rec'))
    ));

  // The rest of my custom functions

  }
}
```

**behat.yml**

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
      - FeatureContext
      - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
      - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
      - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
      - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
    extensions:
      DMore\ChromeExtension\Behat\ServiceContainer\ChromeExtension: ~
      Behat\MinkExtension:
        browser_name: chrome
        base_url: http://www.spheria.rec
        sessions:
          default:
            chrome:
              api_url: http://localhost:9222

    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      blackbox: ~
```

**test.feature**

```
Feature: Sample feature
    Scenario: Arrived on website, checking out what's around me
      Given I am an anonymous user
      And I go to "/"
      And I should see "Se connecter"
      And I should see "Nom d'utilisateur"
      And I should see "Mot de passe"
      When I fill in "admin@spheria.com" for "name"
      And I fill in "admin" for "pass"
      And I press "Se connecter"
      Then I should get a 200 HTTP response
      And the url should match "/dashboard"
      And I should see "Tableau de bord"
```

My problem is that if I use MinkContext in the behat file and in FeatureContext, the consoles returns me that every single function have been declared twice (at least, `MincContext::PressButton` but I wouldn't be surprised if the problem would happen with something else)

When I remove it from both `behat.yml` and FeatureContext, it doesn't recognize anything, and asks me to define these functions, which makes sense I guess.

And when I use MinkContext in only the behat file or the FeatureContext one, I get an error saying this:

> Mink instance has not been set on Mink context class. Have you enabled the Mink Extension? (RuntimeException)

I'm using the DMore Chrome Driver, because I have trouble running Chrome with Selenium properly, and I have the feeling that instancing Mink in the constructor is creating some troubles.

It's an euphemism to say that I'm totally lost on what I should do.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `extend MinkContext` only once else it will see duplicate steps for each time you extend it.

One of the contexts from `behat.yml` is already extending `MinkContext` so you need to:

1. remove that class and extend it in your `FeatureContext`

or

2. your `FeatureContext` should not extend `MinkContext` but `RawMinkContext`